# How to set only part of a string in a variable

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a simple Skype bot that will give a response when the user sends a message with the option.

My issue is when the user responds with `"!resolve username"` it tries to resolve the whole string.

How would I just select the username from the response and place it that in a variable?

```
 ElseIf msg = "resolve" Or msg = "Resolve" Then
    'send the usernamer to sever and saves response in var

    Dim resolvedIP As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(
        "http://api.c99.nl/skyperesolver.php?key=korrupted.1020ull&username=" + 
        pMessage.Body)

    'prints IP
    c.SendMessage(resolvedIP)
```

Comment: Please don't call methods directly on a `new WebClient()` as it is an `IDisposable` class and should be disposed of after use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you need?

```
Dim username = _
    Regex _
        .Match("!resolve user3812866", "^!resolve (.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) _
        .Groups(1) _
        .Value
```

Now `username` equals `"user3812866"`.